# dotnet.exe won't run because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to host an **ASP.NET Core 2.0** app in IIS on **Windows Server 2008 R2 SP**1. I'm following the Docs guide on how to [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

After installation, I still can't run `dotnet.exe`. It calls for a DLL named `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`.

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

However, there are *lots* of instances of this file on the machine, in the following folders:

- `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.3`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.3`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18972_none_a9a51144251fb166`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23175_none_aa31870f3e3ad077`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23656_none_aa4830af3e29a3af`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18972_none_4d8675c06cc24030`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23175_none_4e12eb8b85dd5f41`
- `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23656_none_4e29952b85cc3279`

The instruction says:

> Install the **.NET Core Windows Server Hosting** bundle on the hosting system. [...] If the system doesn't have an Internet connection, obtain and install the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable** before installing the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle.

I have installed/repaired both of these packages multiple times but get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably not that the DLL is *missing*, but rather one of the DLL's dependencies is missing.

1. Make sure you're installing the [Update 3 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) of the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.
2. One of the requirements of the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable is [KB2999226](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49062). Make sure this is installed as well.

   - If it's already installed, post the installation log from the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable installer package.

Answer (score 2):

on windows server 2012 R2
I had same issue. Windows update + installing windows specific update solved it.

see: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4388.

I installed this update:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118401/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Install these Windows 8.1 updates **in this order**:

1. KB2919442
2. KB2919355
3. KB2999226

After installing the above 3 Windows update in the correct order, the error about the missing `dll` should stop.

---

I ran into basically this same problem when attempting to deploy a **.NET Core 2.1** application to a **Windows 2012 R2** machine. The root cause seems to have been due to a corrupt installation of the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable`.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads):

> Visual C++ Redistributable Packages install runtime components of
> Visual C++ Libraries on a computer that does not have Visual C++
> installed. The libraries are required to run applications that are
> developed by using the corresponding version of Visual C++.

After some troubleshooting and research, I fixed the issue by manually installing these 3 Windows updates ***in this order***:

1. [KB2919442](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42153)
2. [KB2919355](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334) (requires a reboot)
3. [KB2999226](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49077)

**The order of installation of these Windows updates is important!** KB2999226 depends on KB2919355, and KB2919355 depends on KB2919442.

After installing those Windows updates, `dotnet.exe` and the application began to run correctly.